# Handle exception thrown by a task

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

I have a task running a long time operation in WPF:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        process(cancelTokenSource.Token, CompressionMethod, OpInfo);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        logger.Info("Operation cancelled by the user");
    }
}, cancelTokenSource.Token);

try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    int i = 0;
}     


private void process(CancellationToken token, CompressionLevel level, OperationInfo info)
{
    // check hash
    if (ComputeHash)
    {
        logger.Info("HASH CHECKING NOT IMPLEMENTED YET!");
        MessageBox.Show(this,"HASH CHECKING NOT IMPLEMENTED YET!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    UserMsgPhase = "Operation finished";

    return info;
}
```

Problem is "MessageBox.Show" throws an exception and it is not captured within "catch (AggregateException ae)". I've been reading about TPL exception handling but I don't understand why it is not catched. Please, could you help me?

Comment: What type of exception is being thrown? You only catch `OperationCanceledException`, so if it's not that then of course it's not going to be captured. Your second try-catch, with the `AggregateException` is on a completely different block so that catch isn't relevant at all to your `process()` call. You should post a more complete code sample.

Comment: The inner exception is {"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}. But the point is I want to notify calling thread (not thread where exception occurs) that operation failed. If I don't catch the exception, shouldn't be captured by AggregateException catch?

Comment: It would only be captured by your AggregateException catch if it throws an AggregateException. I'm not super great with multithreading though to help you, unfortunately. But basically you have something other than your UI thread trying to manipulate the UI (the message box), which it can't do, so that's why it's erroring out on you.

Comment: Also, even if it were throwing the right exception, since the try-catch that isn't nested in the *other* try catch, it wouldn't be catching it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Once the task is complete you can check its Exception property. You also have Status and IsCompleted properties which may be useful to you...

Answer (score 0):

Check [Task.Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
If your task is typed (returning a result), then accessing myTask.Result will throw this exception.

Moreover, if you are running .Net 4.5, you could use async/await.

As an example:

```
public async void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Task t = ...your task...;
        var myResult = await t; // do whatever you like with your task's result (if any)
    }catch
    {
        // whatever you need
    }
}
```

as you would do with synchronous code (but this is not an actual synchronous call)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the question's `process` method is a `Task`, so it looks like it could be implement in a different manner:

1. You can make the process to be implemented as `Task` and then you will have a task-child within task-parent.
2. Then you can make use of the `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` option.

According to [Stephen Toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5/), using `AttachedToParent` will help notify children-task exception to the parent-task catch:

> any exceptions from faulted children will propagate up to the parent
>   Task (unless the parent Task observes those exceptions before it
>   completes).

### Example:

*I've omitted the cancellation token parts in order for it to be more simple.*

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var process = new Task(() =>
    {
        //Copy here the process logic. 
    }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    //*Private failure handler*.

    process.start();
});

try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    //handle exceptions from process.
}
```

In addition, you may add a private failure handler like:

```
//*Private failure handler*.
var failHandler = child.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    //Oops, something went wrong...
}, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent|TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```